# How to apply *ngFor in angular2 or in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on Ionic Project. Here on button click, a request is process and data is received as shown following:

```
   public login() {
    //this.showLoading()
    var test33;
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data["_body"])
      test33 = data["_body"]
      console.log(test33)
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }
```

In view:

```
 <ion-row class="logo-row">
        <ion-col></ion-col>
        <h2  *ngFor="let user0 of test33">{{ user0.name }}</h2>
        <ion-col width-67>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"/>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col></ion-col>
      </ion-row>`
```

On console I Receiving the data in test33 variable as:

```
 [{"id":1,"role_id":1,"name":"Dr. Admin","email":"admin@admin.com","avatar":"\/user\/1\/profile\/HR1-dummy-avater.png","password":"$2y$10$iEpnh6pJ09rxH5NFFCVzaewBCxC\/FHZuHnkWA6qUrOBO3tYIBbsVC","remember_token":"VgwXUdIpL6EqW7Fp66VGRPjSKE727Inc4MTseJQq84cTCglkS335KCqVnavu","created_at":"2017-05-25 22:46:10","updated_at":"2017-06-14 05:19:52","is_feature":null}]
```

But `{{user0.name}}` not returning the name.

Please Point out where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using test33 as a variable but not a property, this means that ngFor cant look test33 on the properties of the component.

So you have to do is declare test33 as property `this.test33;` and then ngFor would know about that property.

**Keep in mind**
If you want to use vars from your code on the template you have to declare them as component properties.

Hope this help you.

EDIT:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  test33;
  andAnyPropYouWantHere;

  constructor() {}

}
```

Then all the props you declare there you can use on the template with ngFor, ngIf, and so much others :)

Comment: How to declare it as property. because now when I am comment out the `var test33` and change the `test33` to this.test33` its throwing an error of  `Property 'test33' does not exist on type 'LoginPage'.`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `test33` is a local variable, and **not a property from the component**, so the view can't access to its value.

To fix it, declare `test33` as a property from the component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    public test33: any;

    //...

}
```

and then set its value in the `login()` method using `this.test33`:

```
public login() {
    //this.showLoading()
    // var test33; <- remove this line
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data["_body"])
      this.test33 = data["_body"]
      console.log(this.test33)
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }
```

And now it should be shown in the view as expected.

Comment: Yeah, we both added the answer at the same time, sorry!. Glad to help :)